# python regex to match words

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm attempting to check if the desc starts with [ab] and print out the desc

```
import re
desc = "[ab] test"
match = re.search(r"(?<=\[ab\] ).*", desc)
if match != None:
  print(match.group())
```

The expected output is:

```
[ab] test
```

It should match:

```
[ab] apple
[ab] pear
```

It shouldn't match:

```
ab apple
[a] apple
```

The current issue that I'm facing is it displays None.

Comment: The Python script you showed us won't even compile/parse without error.  Please include the actual script you are running along with some sample data.

Comment: @CinCout It is currently printing None. The expected outcome is to print out the desc if it match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added the details

Comment: `re.search(r"(?<=\[ab\] ).*", desc)` should work fine, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assert that the entire input matches `[ab] something`, then use `re.search` with anchors:

```py
desc = "[ab] test"
if re.search(r'^\[ab\] \S+$', desc):
    print("MATCH")
else:
    print("NO MATCH")
```

If you want to extract such matching terms from a larger text, then use `re.findall`:

```py
inp = "ab apple [a] apple [ab] apple blah [ab] pear"
matches = re.findall(r'\[ab\] \S+', inp)
print(matches)  # ['[ab] apple', '[ab] pear']
```

Comment: Hi Tim, what about matching  "[ab] apple pear" using re.search? @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: That sounds like a good starting point for another question (not what you asked here though).